# Open source ATi driver froze after installation and fail to boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, drivers, radeon

I installed today a HD5500 Radeon card in my system today, and installed the open source driver. Following this, my system worked for a while. Though I could see no performance improvement. Then the whole system froze, and I was never able to boot Ubuntu with Unity again.

I can only boot the console now, graphical boot will only result in a black screen.

I tried to remove the open source drivers and install the proprietary drivers , but it didn't help.

Tried to remove the GPU hardware from the system and use the motherboard integrated VGA only, but still no change (got a frozen loading screen instead of pitch dark).

I am not sure of the current state of my drivers, but it's surely messy. I don't even know how to perform a check on that :(

Could you please tell me a way of getting the system to boot again, through a complete cleanup or reinstallation that would hopefully work ?

Comment: As you said you tried to install the proprietary drivers, can you post the output of `/usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log` please? Please also provide any other error messages which may be relevant.

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answer. I am away from the faulty computer right now, I'll only be able to check the log tomorrow. Though I can tell you I did not really see something I could identify as an error message, but again I could have missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I could access again my desktop using the `startx` command, and then used the interface to revert back to my original configuration.

I am running on the proprietary drivers and trying to go back to the open source ones. Strangely enough I have an Unsupported hardware watermark, the GC is a Radeon 5450.

Edit : I reverted with to open-source drivers successfully, but with no performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me I had to restart the compiz plugin in the backend which seemed really hard but actually was not. It appeared that compiz plugin had halted and needed restarting. As a result I had to install a small programme called Compiz Config Setting Manager or CCSM

When you boot up and are stuck with a black screen hit Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get a terminal session

Log in as normal with your username and password

Then type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then run the following command

```
gksudo ccsm
```

which will start up  Compiz Config Setting Manager like this. See the desktop section

[image: CCSM Picture]

If like me this was the issue you will notice that the Unity plugin has been disabled so tick it and then hit close . This 'may' solve the issue you had. You may also have to physically then restart Unity using the following command:

```
unity --reset
```

You may then be able to reinstall the open source drivers which in my experience are a little less crashy on my system with my older ATI graphics card.